# Adding markup to each line of a Wordpress page content using PHP and Regex

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

I'm looking at a Wordpress Custom Field in which the user inputs some text with carriage returns, that will be converted to `<br/>` thanks to `wpautop`.

```
<?php echo wpautop(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'customfield' , true)); ?>
```

**What I need to do next is to add a `<span>` to each of the lines so obtained, in order to apply some styling to the individual lines.**

I'm trying with `preg_replace` and Regex, but this doesn't work:

```
<?php 
$subject = wpautop(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'text1' , true));

$result = preg_replace('/(.*<br>)*/m', '<span>$1</span>', $subject); 
?>

<div><?php echo $result; ?></div>
```

...since it wraps every single character in `<span>` tags!

What is wrong with this: `'/((.*)<br>)*/m'`?

Or maybe there is a better way to do this in php, intercepting `get_post_meta`?

Comment: What is the content of `$subject`? What do you get and what do you expect? Please, edit your question and add these informations if you want us to help you.

Comment: The content of `$subject` is evidently what is returned by `get_post_meta`, which, as I have explained above, consists of "some text with carriage returns that will be converted to <br/>". Nothing more.

Comment: I suggest you to use ACF(Advanced custom fields) plugin insted of using default custom fields.

Comment: @Dev: no thanks, there is no need for me to use that plugin. Everything I need can be done with custom fields. Besides this is not the point of my question, which focuses on manipulating those lines in order to add a <span> tag to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your regex:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(.*<br>)*/m', '<span>$1</span>', $subject);
```

1 - remove the second `*`:

```
 $result = preg_replace('/(.*<br>)/m', '<span>$1</span>', $subject);
```

2 - In your example in comments you have `<br/>`, not `<br>`, make the slash optional:

```
 $result = preg_replace('/(.*<br\/?>)/m', '<span>$1</span>', $subject);
```

3 - Make the `.*` not greedy `.*?`:

```
 $result = preg_replace('/(.*?<br\/?>)/m', '<span>$1</span>', $subject);
```

4 - Change the delimiter to avoid escape the slash:

```
 $result = preg_replace('~(.*?<br/?>)~m', '<span>$1</span>', $subject);
```

5 - may be there're spaces before the slash:

```
 $result = preg_replace('~(.*?<br\s*/?>)~m', '<span>$1</span>', $subject);
```

6 - Have a try.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work! Maybe there is something else wrong on my side. I don't know if [this](https://regex101.com/r/1eWXdV/1) is reliable, but according to them the regex works as expected even in different variations.

Comment: wait, I think the /m multiline switch is wrong for me, since I want the regex to work on each line. according to regex101 the /g switch would work, except that on my web page the /g is rejected as "unknown modifier". How's this possible???

Comment: @nico: There is no `g` modifier in php.

Comment: I get the same string without modifications. Also, I read that the /g switch is implicit, yet even if I remove the /m switch the replacement doesn't happen. I am starting to think that the <br> inserted by wpautop are not matched by my string...

Comment: @nico: Maybe you have `<br />` (a space before the slash)? Or something?

Comment: in the DevTools it appears as a regular <br>

Comment: YES. You were right. Apparently `wpautop` writes `<br>` as `<br />` (with the space AND the slash; these are then beautified to `<br>` by the browser (I assume?). To sum up, this regex works: `'~(.*?<br\s?/?>)~'`

Comment: @nico:Great! Glad it helps.

Comment: ...maybe add the last modification to your answer, so others dealing with wpautop and regex can benefit :)